# Change webview find on page result style using css?

Tags: html, css, webview, electron

In an Electron webview using `findInPage`, can you use css to change the result colors?

[image]

In the above image, the current find result is highlighted in orange while additional results are highlighted with yellow. I'd like to tweak the styling of both of these

Comment: Well, you could override the `Ctrl-F` key event and make it your own.

Comment: @Matt Bierner Is it important to you to implement it with css ? because it's so easy to write with java script.

Comment: I really don't care how it is implemented but unless you can convince me otherwise, reimplementing page search in JS sounds like one of those easy problems that is surprisingly difficult to get correct

Comment: Can I know how did you implement search feature?

Comment: It's built-in to electron. See [`findInPage`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#webviewfindinpagetext-options)

Answer (score 3):

```css
body{
background-color:#000;
color:#fff;
}
h2::-moz-selection { /*Firefox*/
    color: #000;
    background: #FF9800;
}
::-moz-selection { /*Firefox */
    color: #000;
    background: yellow;
}
h2::selection {
    color: #000;
    background: #FF9800;
}
::selection {
       color: #000;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h2>Select some text on this page:</h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>
```

Comment: This does not change the find results. Only the selection colors

Answer (score 0):

In Electron you can use [stopfindInPage](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/#webviewstopfindinpageaction) to stop the find and focus/activate a selection (`activateSelection` - Focus and click the selection node). As it is also possible to [insert css](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/#webviewinsertcsscss), this may allow you to insert css to update the color/ bg=color of the selected text,  by using something like the following :

```
::selection {
  background: #ffb7b7; /* WebKit/Blink Browsers */
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: #ffb7b7; /* Gecko Browsers */
}
```

I haven't tried it, it's just a suggestion from looking at the API.
There is an interesting article on [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/) that you may also find useful

Hope this helps, and that you find a solution

**EDIT:**

If you are on mac you could use [setUserDefault](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/system-preferences.md#systempreferencessetuserdefaultkey-type-value-macos) in the system preferences.

In addition, if you use [Nathan Buchar's electron settings](https://github.com/nathanbuchar/electron-settings), you can use the [set](https://github.com/nathanbuchar/electron-settings/wiki/API-Documentation#set) method to adjust key values (in mac/windows/linux - see his [faq](https://github.com/nathanbuchar/electron-settings/wiki/FAQs#where-is-the-settings-file-saved))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, selection css doesn't handle the find in page matches. Your reply did inspire me to look through the chromium source though, and I believe that found the source find match colors: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/layout/LayoutTheme.cpp?dr=CSs&l=816  Looks like they are hardcoded?

Comment: @MattBierner see these links; this first one was suggested by a developer on a chrome forum: https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/color.html . also investigate https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html and https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements-styles

Comment: @MattBierner the first link was suggested in reply to a query to how to change the background color  in chrome but I'm sure it can be adapted to change only the background of selected text. Here's the forum link: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BnLnYe3SK8k (it's marked as the best answer)

Comment: Thanks again. I gave you the bounty for providing some interesting lines to investigate and for the good followup, even though I don't think these answer the question yet

Comment: @MattBierner thanks a mil! i've been offline for a few hours so only saw i earned the bounty now, so thanks v much. glad i could help at least , if not answer .. (you should post the solution if you find one! :) )